# dimension of matrices

Tags: matrices

How is the dimension of a matrix defined? It normally refers to the number of rows and columns of a given matrix, but in the book I am reading (matrix computations by Gill) a single number is used. For instance, a subspace contains vectors of dimension $3$,  meaning $3 \times 1$ matrices. How do I get that number?

Comment: Normally one defines the **dimension** of a vector space as the number of elements in (any) basis of that vector space. It is not usual to define a "dimension" of a matrix, I think. The set of $m\times n$ matrices (over a field) does form a vector space over that field, though, and that space has dimension $mn$, the product of $m$ and $n$, which is the number of entries in each matrix in the set.

Comment: @Jeppe: this is an answer not comment, :-)

Comment: @SergioParreiras I made it an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

*(promoted from comment)*

Normally one defines the **dimension** of a vector space as the number of elements in (any) basis of that vector space.

It is not usual to define a "dimension" of a matrix, I think. The set of $m\times n$  matrices (over a field) does form a vector space over that field, though, and that space has dimension $mn$, the product of $m$ and $n$, which is the number of entries in each matrix in the set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I highly doubt it is the case in the book.